# Disabling Mouse-wheel on Google Map generated by Wordpress Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, wordpress

I'm using the [Simple Locator](https://locatewp.com/) plugin for Wordpress. Because the Google maps are being loaded by the plugin, I don't have control over the map options. I'd like to set scrollwheel: false but I can't seem to get it working.

Is it possible to create a new script that gets the id of the map on the page, and adds new options for it? Something like this:

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false      
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I tried this as well, but it isn't working either. Am I getting any closer?

```
var myOptions = {
    scrollwheel: false,
    navigationControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    draggable: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

map.set(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the plugin and it doesn't have any mechanism to set that option or any actions/filters you could hook into.

If the map object is named `map` on your page, you could try adding the following code towards the footer of your page after the map has been initialized to set that option yourself:

```
map.setOptions( { scrollwheel: false });
```

You can specify any of the options listed [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapOptions) when calling `google.maps.Map.setOptions`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://agilestorelocator.com, the backend provide the ability to disable scrollwheel from wordpress admin panel.

Comment: Are you sure? Coz I am unable to find that option in admin panel.